# Angular2 filter in typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Angular2 typescript search same values from array into object array.
What I want to filter is any of values from array_values exists in object_array['extraService'], if exists return object.
That is Angular Pipe for renering template for somekinde of search function.

```
let array_values = ["5", "4", "3"]
let items = [{'name': "Marin", extraService:[5, 4]}, {'name': "Marin", extraService:[3, 4]}]
```

## Filter by typescript my try

```
return items.filter(item => items.array_values(f => f == item.extraService));
```

So some example what is output.
If array_values is only

```
let array_values = ["3"]
```

then output from return will be:

```
result = [{'name': "Marin", extraService:[3, 4]}]
```

Any advice or sample how can I manage this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
 let array_values = ["5", "4", "3"]
        let items = [{'name': "Marin", extraService:[5, 4]}, {'name': "Marin", extraService:[3, 4]}];

        let results = items.filter(item => {
            const result = item.extraService.filter(extra => {
                return array_values.indexOf(extra.toString()) !== -1;
            });
            if (result.length > 0) return true;
            return false;
        });
        console.log(results);
```

You can try with this approach:

```
 let array_values = ["5", "4", "3"]
    let items = [{'name': "Marin", extraService:[5, 4]}, {'name': "Marin", extraService:[3, 4]}];

    return items.filter(item => {
        const result = item.extraService.filter(extra => {
            return array_values.indexOf(extra.toString()) !== -1;
        });
        if (result.length > 0) return true;
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: @marin in case it matches your answer, please mark it's answer, tks.

Comment: Yea but i want to return match objects, this code returns array_values.

Comment: I will update my question with result what i want to do with filter.

Comment: Tank you for your help.